# how to change cursor while dragging in dragstart or dragover in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to change the cursor while im over the drop zone , I saw these questions but didn't help : [Q1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16259638/changing-cursor-while-dragging) , [Q2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10119514/html5-drag-drop-change-icon-cursor-while-dragging) and [Q3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68232837/javascript-change-dragging-cursor?rq=3) ,
Here is what i tried . first I tried change it in dragstart and dragover by using :

```
 event.target.style.cursor = "grabbing";
```

it didn't work the cursor actually change when the dragend but whenever i try to drag it again it not working. Second try I created a css class and add it to the `event.target.classList.add('cursor-grabbing');`
in dragstart and dragover but the same result as the first try , Last thing i tried is :

```
 event.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'grabbing';
```

this the cursor i want to change (the arrow while dragging ) :

[image]

Comment: can you provide [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) snippet to replicate the behavior?

Answer (score 0):

You already noticed that [CSS cursor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/cursor) and [the dropEffect property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer/dropEffect) are not the same. You can also see that in this example where the cursor on the `<body>` is a pointer and on the `<li>` elements a move cursor.

When dragging a draggable element the CSS cursor is overruled by the drag'n'drop functionality.

The dropEffect only applies to the area with the dragover event listener. In my example there are four `<ul>`'s with a dragover event listener. Each with the different effects `move`, `copy`, `link` and then one without an effect. You can see, when you drag over each the cursor changes. The appearance of the cursor depends on the browser and OS. If you drag over the fourth `<ul>` without effect defined, you can try to press Ctrl, Shift and Ctrl+Shift to see the different effects. So, the dropEffect is not for "any" cursor -- it is only intended for the same effect you have in you OS when you drag a file, an image or whatever.

I also have a bit of code the is commented out. It's an event listener for dragover event on `<body>` -- so the cursor can actually be "styled" all over the document.

```js
document.querySelector('ul').addEventListener('dragstart', e => {
  e.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain", e.target.dataset.id);
});

/*document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('dragover', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'link';
});*/

document.querySelector('.droplists').addEventListener('dragover', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  if(e.target.dataset.effect)
    e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = e.target.dataset.effect;
  let ul = e.target.closest('ul.drop');
  if (ul) ul.classList.add('over');
});

document.querySelector('.droplists').addEventListener('dragleave', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let ul = e.target.closest('ul.drop');
  if (ul) ul.classList.remove('over');
});

document.querySelector('.droplists').addEventListener('drop', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let id = e.dataTransfer.getData("text/plain");
  let ul = e.target.closest('ul.drop');
  if (ul) {
    ul.classList.remove('over');
    let li = document.createElement('li');
    li.textContent = `Item with the id ${id}`;
    ul.appendChild(li);
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  cursor: pointer;
}

ul li {
  cursor: move;
}

.drop {
  border: solid 2px navy;
  width: 100px;
  min-height: 100px;
}

.drop.over {
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.droplists {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li data-id="1" draggable="true">Drag me 1</li>
  <li data-id="2" draggable="true">Drag me 2</li>
  <li data-id="3" draggable="true">Drag me 3</li>
</ul>
<div class="droplists">
  <ul data-effect="move" class="drop"></ul>
  <ul data-effect="copy" class="drop"></ul>
  <ul data-effect="link" class="drop"></ul>
  <ul class="drop"></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: you just changing what next to the cursor (copy , move ...) and not the cursor itself, what i really want is to change the arrow itself while Im dragging over ,get it ?